# Circular menu in a responsive bootstrap website // how to maintain menu button positions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I created a horizontally sliding website, its a one wide container site with 500% width and 5 sections each 20% width. I found a CSS jquery circular menu that I manipulated to my requirements and fixed it so it is fixed in the center when the website is flowing right and left, unfortunately when I resized the page or changed the resolution, the menu page alignment failed . Yesterday, I decided to change the website to be a responsive design website and I used bootstrap to accomplish this and it worked. the problem is with the circular menu. I managed to fix its position to be centered even when I change the browser width, but the menu items don't move with the menu button, it moves in a different direction ,so its not aligned on small width. How can I stick the menu items to the menu itself ?

The menu code HTML code:

```
<div class="circular-menu">
            <div class="circle">

               <ul id="nav" class="cirular-list navbar-default" >
                        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>              
                        <li><a href="#OurWork">Our Work</a></li>            
                        <li><a href="#Technologies">Technologies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#AboutUs">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

                <a href="" class="menu-button"><img id="Img1" runat="server" src="Images/c1.jpg" /></a>

            </div>
```

The Menu CSS:

```
body
{
    background:#ffffff;
    }
.circular-menu {
list-style:none;
   margin: 30% 0% 0% 22%;


}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0;


  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;

}
.cirular-list
{
    list-style:none;
    position:inherit;

    }

.open.circle {
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.circle a {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 30%;
    width: 30%;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-left: -19%;
    margin-top: -8%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;

}

.circle a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  font-style:underlined;
}

.menu-button {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 40%;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: #444;
border-radius: 50%;
display: block;
height: 100px;
width: 102px;
line-height: 40px;
background: #ffffff;

}
```

The JS:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    items[i].style.left = (50 - 35 * Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2 * (1 / l) * i * Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

    items[i].style.top = (50 + 35 * Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2 * (1 / l) * i * Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}

document.querySelector('.menu-button').onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

The section consist of 3 columns like this:

```
 <div id="ContactUs" class="section row">
            <div class="jumbotron whiteBack">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>    
            </div>        
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
Left part
</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
Circular Menu
</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
Right part
</div>
```

Comment: It gives me error {"error": "Please use POST request"}
http://jsfiddle.net/tzLz1f8a/

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/tzLz1f8a/2/  If so, I'll post an explanation.

Comment: Yes, how did you do it !! This is the menu I am using.

Comment: How Can I maintain the menu Icon aligned with the menu buttons around it when I change resolution or width and hight

Comment: Did you already do it !!, that's awesome :)
Please explain